# My sharedReference file is not creating or there might be some other error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter project. This is my splash screen code.
I had created a splash screen which holds for 3 seconds, then I had initialize the sharedPreference after which I took the email and password from the shared preference file and tried to login. If the login is successfull then there will be no error and the will move to home screen. And if there a error in signing in then the user will move to login screen. Before goin to login screen I had reset the sharedpreference so that trash or irrelevant value will vanished.

```
 @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
       sharedPreference().sharedPrefInit();
       Future<String> email = sharedPreference().getCred('email');
       Future<String> password = sharedPreference().getCred('password');
       print('Email: $email\nPassword $password');
       print('inside initstate');
       firebaseAuth
           .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'email', password: 'password')
           .catchError(
         (errMsg) {
           print('catching error');
           if (errMsg == null) {
             print('inside if $errMsg');
             Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
               context,
               PageRouteBuilder(
                 transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                 transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                   animation = CurvedAnimation(
                       parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                   return ScaleTransition(
                     scale: animation,
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child: child,
                   );
                 },
                 pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                   return HomeScreen(
                     email: 'email',
                   );
                 },
               ),
               (route) => false,
             );
           } else {
             print('inside else $errMsg');
             sharedPreference().reset();
             Navigator.pushReplacement(
               context,
               PageRouteBuilder(
                 transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                 transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                   animation = CurvedAnimation(
                       parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                   return ScaleTransition(
                     scale: animation,
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child: child,
                   );
                 },
                 pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                   return const LoginOrSignUp();
                 },
               ),
             );
           }
         },
       );
     });
   }
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing in it? When I run the application Wheather it's a error or not it always went in else section and move me to login screen.

Here is my sharedPreference Intialize code:

```
Future<void> sharedPrefInit() async {
  try {
    /// Checks if shared preference exist
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.getString("recipedia");
  } catch (err) {
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString("recipedia", "my-app");
  }
}
```

Here is the whole sharedPreference class

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class sharedPreference {
  Future<void> sharedPrefInit() async {
    try {
      /// Checks if shared preference exist
      Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
      prefs.getString("recipedia");
    } catch (err) {
      SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
      Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
      prefs.setString("recipedia", "my-app");
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveCred(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString("email", email);
    prefs.setString("password", password);
  }

  Future<String> getCred(key) async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    String result = prefs.getString("$key").toString();
    return result;
  }

  void reset() async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you're using Future of String not String value. note:

```
Future<String> email = sharedPreference().getCred('email');
Future<String> password = sharedPreference().getCred('password');
```

second, you're not really using them, you're trying to login with the string 'email' and the string 'password' not there value. note:

```
FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'email', password: 'password')
```

what you should do is to make the function asynchronous and:

```
String email = await sharedPreference().getCred('email');
String password = await sharedPreference().getCred('password');

FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
```

just a note: don't use Timer to delay login, it's not how it works

Comment: I had use timer because it is a splash screen so when ever user open the app the splash screen will display for 3 sec and in the meanwhile the user will be checked that the shared preference email and password is exist in our firebase auth if yes then login